# How do I add cartesian axes to a polar plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I have a polar contour plot, and I want to add cartesian axes to it. How can I do this? There seems to be no documentation for this.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) ** 10 + np.cos(10 + y * x) * np.cos(x)

x = np.linspace(0, 8, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 8, 40)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw = dict(projection = 'polar'))
plt.axis('off')
ax.contourf(X, Y, Z)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add cartesian axes"? Can you please write more than one sentence about the desired outcome? Also, if you want a code-answer, can you make sure the code you show can be used by someone, i.e. is runnable.

Comment: By cartesian axes I mean x and y axes. I just want to know if there is a way to have an x, y scale for a polar plot in matplotlib. You will need the data file to make the graphs, so there's no reason to put all my code.

Comment: Well, there is also no reason for anyone to answer such question which does not provide a [mcve]. Think about it. Anyways, the problem of cartesian axes isn't really clear; what would be the relation between the polar axes and the cartesian ones? [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3q5t.png) is a polar plot with cartesian axes around it. Is that what you want?

Comment: I changed the example. Hopefully this new one can help you understand. Your question on the relation between polar and cartesian coordinates is kind of irrelevant, and well defined if you look up 'polar transformation'. The example you provided in the previous comment is what I am after, except just the cartesian coordinates, not the polar ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add cartesian axes to a polar plot, all you have to do is add a second pair of axes at the same position like so:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) ** 10 + np.cos(10 + y * x) * np.cos(x)

x = np.linspace(0, 8, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 8, 40)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw = dict(projection = 'polar'))
plt.axis('off')
ax.contourf(X, Y, Z)

new_axis = fig.add_axes(ax.get_position(), frameon = False)
new_axis.plot()
plt.show()
```